# Roles functional

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have simple rails app with devise authorization. Models `task` and `user`. I need to implement the functional roles. Task can edit and delete only owner. And owner can add collaborators to his tasks. This task can view only owner and collaborators.

And second question. I need to realize function admin. I think use gem `activeadmin`. But there maybe a better solution?

How I can realize this functional?

Comment: for authorization on model I recommend [CanCan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/) it's fit for your question.

Comment: Can you help me about adapt cancan to my task? I am new at rails and don't understand how do this. And I have subtask, url path `/tasks/:id/subtasks/:id`.

Comment: I creating example in github I will post link to you ASAP.

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/virudson/test-cancan) for the git.
The model design is bad but good for test authorization.

Comment: Just look on `model/ability.rb` **it tell about what this role can do with `Task & SubTask`** and `partials` in views **will tell how to check authorization on `Task&SubTask`.**

If have any question please ask to me. I'm not good with coding too but hope this help you.

PS if you have github user send it to me I will added you to collaboration.

Comment: Awesome! I understand! Thank you! You really helper me! Sure! my github account `Zenya`

Comment: And just one question. If I right understand, I need use cancan authorization instead of devise?

Comment: No you can't, `devise` and `cancan` is not the same :).
For easy to understand `devise` **is use for login system(handle user who use your system)** and `cancan` is for **handle which user is allowed to do something with model(permission to do with model.)**

Comment: That mean you can use other authentication gems eg. `Authlogic` :D

Comment: And this I understand too. Thank you.

Comment: But I have small problem, my project has next structure: `projects/:id/tasks/:id/subtasks/:id`. And I know this it is not desirable (Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.), but another way I don't khow.
Project owner can invite members. For this I create some table `members`, and inside was structure `user_id`, `project_id` and `role`(e.g: as `owner/member`). For example project owner can `:manage` everything about his project. Invited member can only `:create/:update/:delete` his `tasks/subtasks`. How I can realize this in `ability.rb`?

Comment: Look at [this wiki page](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities). All you can play with `ability.rb` in there. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this my own question after 2 years xD

And 2 years I use `Cancan`. Awesome gem!

Comment: `cancan` is dead use [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) instead.
And another choice is [access-granted](https://github.com/chaps-io/access-granted) gem.